# Adding Some View to RecyclerView item programmatically creates an known bug

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-livedata, android-binding-adapter

So I,m creating a todo app where user can set priority and priority stars are added programmatically through binding adapter but when scrolling the tasks recycler view Tasks with zero no of stars are also showing stars wheres checking Log it shows zero stars. Also this bug occurs only when i scroll to item with stars and then start scrolling rigorously

1. App just started

[image]

2. Scrolled to Item with tasks Star

[image]

3. After Scrolling rigorously

[image]

I have tried Creating New ArrayList everyTime item is updated

Fragment Code :

```
viewModel.taskCategory.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { taskCategoryPair ->
            taskCategoryPair?.let {
                Log.i("HomeFragment","Submitting New List")
                viewModel.filterDataFinish()
                adaptor.submitList(it)
            }
        })
```

RecyclerView bind code :

```
 RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(
            task: ToDo,
            category: Category,
            clickListener: MiscellaneousUtils.GetIdFromClick
        ) {
            binding.task = task
            binding.category = category
            binding.clickListener = clickListener
            binding.onCheckChangeListener = categorizedTasksClickListeners

            binding.root.setOnLongClickListener {
                categorizedTasksClickListeners.onLongClickItem(adapterPosition,it)
                true
            }

            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }
```

BindingAdapter function which add stars :

```
@BindingAdapter("app:setPriority")
fun LinearLayoutCompat.setPriority(task: ToDo) {
    if (task.priorityStars == 0)
        return

    val previousStarContainer = findViewWithTag<LinearLayout>("starContainerLayout")

    if (previousStarContainer != null) {
        removeView(previousStarContainer)
    }

    val starContainer = LinearLayout(context)
    starContainer.tag = "starContainerLayout"
    starContainer.layoutParams = LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )

    for (count in 1..task.priorityStars) {
        val starView = ImageView(context)
        starView.setImageResource(R.drawable.task_star)
        starView.layoutParams = LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
        starContainer.addView(starView)
    }
    addView(starContainer)

}
```

Comment: you should have shared source code for you adapter and viewholder instead

Comment: @AdeelTurk  Updated the question with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recycler recycle views :) - It uses same view to show multiple data! That means that a view can be used to show an object with stars - so on `onBindViewHolder` you show the stars. And then the same view (with stars now) will be used to show a different object (no star object) - it means that on `onBindViewHolder` you will now need to hide the stars, which I bet you didn't ;)

As I said, if you have no stars you don't remove the previous starts :

```
if (task.priorityStars == 0)
        return
```

Change your code to:

```
@BindingAdapter("app:setPriority")
fun LinearLayoutCompat.setPriority(task: ToDo) {
    val previousStarContainer = findViewWithTag<LinearLayout>("starContainerLayout")

    if (previousStarContainer != null) {
        removeView(previousStarContainer)
    }

    if (task.priorityStars == 0)
        return

    val starContainer = LinearLayout(context)
    starContainer.tag = "starContainerLayout"
    starContainer.layoutParams = LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )

    for (count in 1..task.priorityStars) {
        val starView = ImageView(context)
        starView.setImageResource(R.drawable.task_star)
        starView.layoutParams = LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
        starContainer.addView(starView)
    }
    addView(starContainer)

}
```

Comment: It worked man! But why only stars were reused not other data like checkBox ,task title or other? Also for how long are working with android?

Comment: Woman. The whole view is being reused, you probably change all the other stuff.

Comment: Also previously i was using a onCheckChangeListener on checkbox and similar problem occurred ie when i scroll up and down automatically items would be checked or unchecked.Can you please explain this

Comment: might be you only "checked" items need to be checked and forgot to "uncheck" items?

Comment: meaning you changed everything else in fun bind()

Comment: checked was set using android:checked="@{task.isCompleted}".so i  think that would not be the problem